# PWA beforeinstallprompt Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

The below function works fine when a user installs the pwa. If they decline however, the next time they come on to the site, `deferredPrompt.prompt();` throws the `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` exception, even though `deferredPrompt.prompt();` is not undefined.

Is there something I need to check for regarding a users previously given answer?

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    //e.preventDefault();

    let deferredPrompt;

    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e;
    // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

Comment: Got the same error, did you solve it? I copied the snipped directly from PWA builder

Comment: @Madeo unfortunately not. If I ever do I'll come back here and post an answer

Comment: I´m having the same issue. No solutions until now?

Answer (score 6):

I have similar code and encounter the same problem. After some researches, I understand that `deferredPrompt.prompt()` will return a `userResponsePromise` which is a promise. Then I try to see what happen by adding this line of code to observe the log.

```
deferredPrompt.prompt()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(error => { console.log(`----> ${error}`) })
```

at the console log, it shows

```
----> NotAllowedError: The prompt() method must be called with a user gesture
```

I guess the A2HS installation process may not allow calling `prompt()` directly.
Therefore I try to change my code to by setup a call to action button that will call `prompt()` method which I suppose it should imply to the meaning of 'user gesture' as the log suggest.

Here is my new code which is look like the code from [Add to Home Screen tutorial from Google dev.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) (I don't know why I didnot follow it at the first time :P)

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  deferredPrompt = e
})

const btnInstallApp = document.getElementById('btn-install-app')

if(btnInstallApp) {
  btnInstallApp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    deferredPrompt.prompt()
    deferredPrompt.userChoice
      .then(choiceResult => {
        if(choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
          console.log('user accepted A2HS prompt')
        } else {
          console.log('user dismissed A2HS prompt')
        }
        deferredPrompt = null
      })
    })
}
```

The I add my Install App button somewhere in the page

```
<button id="btn-install-app" class="btn">Install App</button>
```

This time I can see the Add to Homescreen prompt after I click the Install App button.
I hope this help.

Comment: I was getting the error when trying to activate the A2HS from a CreateJS/ZIMjs canvas library mousedown event.  As soon as I overlaid an HTML button, the error went away.  So... too bad the system does not recognize canvas events as a "gesture" it usually does.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull!

My pwa code is similar and worked ok. However, suddently, after a trivial change in code, I got this error in debug mode using chrome developer tools.

I noticed that I had set a breakpoint imediately before deferredPromt.prompt(). This caused the error because the listener sets a timer in order to detect if event was due to a user gesture.

Unsetting the breakpoint my code worked again.